# How do I constantly check the height of the image that's visible?

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I have a slider of images and need the height of the slider to always be the same height as the currently visible image within the slider.

I've setup this code to automatically check the height of image within the slider, but it's only checking the first image. When the slider rotates to the next image, the height of the slider goes to "0px", but when the slider comes back to the first image, its correctly registers the height.

How do I get this code to correctly register the height of the current slider image and apply this height to the slider.

HTML

```
<div class="slider">
    <img src="#"/>
    <img src="#"/>
    <img src="#"/>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
function checkForChanges() {
    var cool = $('.slider img').height() + "px";
    $('.slider').css('height', cool);
}
setInterval(checkForChanges, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a vanilla javascript solution.

You will need to assign the class '**slide-img**' to each image for it to work. You'll need to fill in the meat of the for loop. But this will get the height of each image.

```
(function checkHeight() {

    // Create array of images
    let arr_imgs = document.querySelectoryAll('.slide-img');

    // for each image -> do somthing
    arr_imgs.forEach(function(e) {

        let imgHeight = e.clientHeight();

    });


});
```